# PayPal purchase of merchandise with middle man fee

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I am developing a mobile app that will allow users to post clothing items for sale. These users will essential load how their inventory and amount of sizes for each product. Then users will be able to come and purchase these item and I will collect a percentage per sale. Sellers will need to get the shipping information and buyers a receipt. What is the best way to do this. Can I set up Paypal to allow users to enter inventory, prices etc, and when a sell is made out fee is automatically with drawn. Or will users have to pay me and then I send the money to the seller along with shipping information.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this. One is [MassPay](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside). There's a fee to send money to your end seller but if you limited their ability to do that, you could send them money anytime you wanted. Has fewer questions for you and is more straightforward.

The other is a bit more complex. It's called [Chained Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/) and it works where you receive the money and then pass the money directly along in the same payment.